# Master-worker model and hybrid MPI/OpenMP

Tags: mpi, openmp

For a software package I developed, I use a master / worker scheme, where one process distributes work to the other processes. The work distributed is independent, but takes highly variable amounts of time to complete, and greatly benefits from a shared memory environment. So, right now I have one process / node, so that each MPI process has, e.g., 12 processors, and a shared memory environment to run OpenMP on. This is all great, but then my "master" process has 11 idle processors, and 1 just distributing work =( I have a few ideas to remedy this, and am looking for any input or other ideas:

- On the master node, allocate one processor to distribute work, and
  the other 11 to actually do work. Conceptually this seems like an
  obvious solution, but I haven't been able to figure out how to actually
  implement such a scheme.
- Have the master node distribute all work via non-blocking sends as
  soon as the program starts, then partake in completing the work. Again, this is conceptually simple, but don't know if MPI actually supports such a scheme (I don't think it does). This would have say, 100 messages sent, waiting to be received by any single process.
- Have all processes load data for all assigned work, and start at different points. When a process begins a task, broadcast to all other processes that this task is underway, so it will not be chosen by another process. This seems like the best choice, but I'm concerned about two processes picking a task simultaneously before the broadcast has reached them. Although it's unlikely that two processes would be picking a new task at exactly the same time, it certainly seems possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is pretty straightforward to implement. First, create an MPI hostfile that looks something like this (Open MPI format):

```
node1 slots=2
node2 slots=1
node3 slots=1
node4 slots=1
```

Then run with:

```
mpiexec --hostfile hostfile.txt -n 2 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=11 a.out : \
                                -n 3 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=12 a.out
```

What will happen is that two copies of `a.out` will be started on `node1` and will become ranks 0 and 1. For those the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` will be set to 11. Assuming that rank 0 is the master process and that it does not execute OpenMP parallel regions, the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is irrelevant to it. Otherwise, you can easily prevent any OpenMP code from using more than one thread by explicitly calling `omp_set_num_threads(1)`. Rank 1 will be one of the workers and it will make use of 11 threads in the parallel regions. On the rest of the nodes only one MPI process will be started and the value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` will be set to 12, so there the OpenMP runtime will use all CPUs. Those processes will become ranks 2, 3, and 4. Worker 1 will be a bit slower, but you already say that your work items take variable time to complete, so I guess there is some kind of work balancer built in.

You can also create a master/worker hybrid for rank 0. You can:

- Run the master and the worker code in separate threads. This will complicate the master code as this particular worker will have to obtain work via a different mechanism, e.g. via a shared-memory queue or something, than the rest of the workers. It is also possible to have the mater send messages to itself, but then it will require an MPI implementation capable of `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`, which usually brings other, mostly performance, problems.
- Fuse the master code with the worker one, especially when the worker code performs some kind of a loop. In that specific case you can post a non-blocking receive for work results and then use `MPI_Test` in each iteration of the worker loop to determine if a result message has arrived. If so, run one iteration of the master loop, post a new non-blocking receive and  continue with the worker iterations. Or use `MPI_Iprobe` instead of non-blocking receives.

Both will increase significantly the complexity of the code, with the second one completely messing up the master/worker code separation. I'd rather stick with the obvious solution above.

Comment: How do I get the name of the node if I am submitting to a large system though? If there's 500 nodes, I'm only asking for say, 25, and which ones will be determined by the system scheduler...

Comment: That would depend on the batch system in use. Some would allow you to request certain distribution of slots. Others would provide the name of the hostfile or the entire host list in environment variables. You could write a script to transform those into an appropriate MPI hostfile.